# SODAQ integrations in Thingsboard without T-Mobile NB-IoT access to the platform

Tags: thingsboard

We are trying to integrate SnifferBike SODAQ sensors in ThingsBoard.
However, according the guide here https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/sodaq/sodaq/ , T-Mobile NB-IoT Platform Callback configuration is needed.

The problem is that is we do not have access for this platform. Are there any alternative ways?
Is the original metadata needed from the devices?

The problem is that all the guidelines are just describing the procedures for the connectivity but not on how to actually receive the data from physical devices.

Thank you very much!